# Creating UML Class diagram?

Tags: java, uml

I am new to UML Class diagrams. Could someone explain to me how I would make one out of this Java code? I have been reading about UML Class diagrams but I can't understand it because of the examples used. So I was wondering of anyone could tell me how to make a UML Class diagram out of my own code.

```
package UserName;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class UserName extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 

    JTextField fname = new JTextField(); 
    JTextField lname = new JTextField();
    JTextField uname = new JTextField(); 
    JTextField email = new JTextField(); 
    JTextArea dataArea = new JTextArea(20, 50); 
    JButton save = new JButton("Save"); 


    Student student[] = new Student[20];
    int count = 0; 


    public UserName() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel();
        fieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 4)); 
        fieldPanel.add(new JLabel("Firstname"));
        fieldPanel.add(fname);
        fieldPanel.add(new JLabel("Username")); 
        fieldPanel.add(uname);
        fieldPanel.add(new JLabel("Lastname")); 
        fieldPanel.add(lname); 
        fieldPanel.add(new JLabel("Email")); 
        fieldPanel.add(email); 
        email.setEnabled(false); 
        uname.setEnabled(false); 
        email.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK); 

        uname.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        this.add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
        this.add(new JScrollPane(dataArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(save, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        save.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserName namn = new UserName(); 
        namn.pack();
        namn.setVisible(true); 
        namn.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (count == 20) { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are 20 students!"); 
            return;
        }
        Student s = new Student();  
        s.fName = fname.getText(); 
        s.eName = lname.getText(); 
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        int iYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String year = (iYear + "").substring(2);
        s.Uname = "a" + year + s.fName.substring(0, 3).toLowerCase() + s.eName.substring(0, 3).toLowerCase();
        s.eMail = s.Uname + "@ltu.com";
        student[count] = s; 
        count++; 
        dataArea.setText("");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
            dataArea.append(student[i].toString() + "\n");
        }

        uname.setText(s.Uname); 
        email.setText(s.eMail); 
    }
}

class Student { 

    String fName; 
    String eName; 
    String Uname; 
    String eMail; 


    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return "Firstname: " + fName + " Lastname: " + eName + " Username: " + Uname + ", Email: " + eMail;
    }

}
```

I would also like to know what software I should use to create UML Diagrams. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [From Java code to UML diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687323/from-java-code-to-uml-diagram)

Comment: As an example, check out [The ObjectAid UML Explorer for Eclipse](http://www.objectaid.com/class-diagram).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I great piece of freeware that you can use is ArgoUML (http://argouml.tigris.org/). This will allow you to enter all of the classes, variables and methods and relationships between the classes to generate a UML class diagram.

You must first have an understanding of the working of UML class diagrams and of how the UML should appear before attempting to use ArgoUML. Using ArgoUML should, however, help you understand the conversion that takes place between the code and diagram.

In your case, it will be quite a simple UML class diagram consisting of two classes. Just create the classes in ArgoUML, start adding variables and methods and it will soon make sense (I hope!).